# Meteor audio calling

Tags: meteor

I am building chat app and want to add voice chat feature. I came across webRTC protocol and there is [package](https://github.com/foxdog-studios/meteor-webrtc) available for it in Meteor. But I found that it is developed for browsers. So if I used it in my application, I believe it will only work on the browser version.

Is there a way to implement audio calling feature that will work on IOS and Android as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS and Android (*Cordova*), you need to use Cordova or PhoneGap package which implements WebRTC protocol and API.

You can easily google it, for reference take a look on [phonertc](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc) package. I've used it in a few projects and can confirm what it works inside of Meteor app.

Comment: can you please check this question if you have the experience to provide me with the answers. I will thankful to you. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537083/hosting-meteor-application