# Hosting Meteor Application

Tags: meteor

I am building Meteor application which I want to later publish it on IOS and Android.

My questions are:

1) Is it possible to host my Meteor application on my own Ubuntu server?

2) Because Meteor server and client sides are bundled into one. How will the Mobile versions connect to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. You can host a Meteor app in all sorts of places including your own server. [Galaxy](https://galaxy.meteor.com/) and [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) are both popular cloud options.
2. When you build for iOS and/or Android you end up with apps that you can post to the App Store and Google Play. The server code is *not* bundled into these. Meteor's [mobile guide](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html) describes how all this works in detail. The server address is configured via the `ROOT_URL` ([docs](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#configuring-server-for-hot-code-push)). Essentially the client has the server's address configured into it so it knows where "home" is. This should obviously not be an IP address since that can change.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes. Ubuntu, Debian, and other Linux distributions will work well too.
2. Over DDP (WebSockets) or XHR, if WebSockets fail to connect. It's the same as in browser, in fact Cordova (*which is used in Meteor to build "native" app*) is a wrapper around Safari in iOS and Chrome in Android, kind of full-screen/interface-less browser, with bindings to native Swift/Objective-C/Java.